# How to detect shape perfect intersection of 2 UIImageViews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

Please, how can I detect precise intersection between 2 imageviews. In each image view is transparent png and I don't want to detect intersection within theirs rectangle frames rather theirs real shapes? Thank for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You would use CGRectIntersectsRect() to see if any UIImageView is intersecting with another.

Comment: not really. as i wrote, i don't to detect their rectangle frames - I'm working with no regular shapes as square, or rectangle. I need pixel perfect detection for shape of tree and a ball.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this will be your answer certainly

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(imageview1.frame, imageview2.frame)) {

//They are intersecting
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[DCInstrospec](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect)
DCIntrospect will help you

Comment: hm, I found this useful but not in this case i think. How would you use this to solve my problem?

Comment: oh, I guess I misunderstand you issues. This tools can help you debug your views. but if you want to determine whether two views intersect, maybe you should the function CGRectIntersectsRect, Just like other guys suggest.